Help me to identify an SMD component marked 'NM' in an SOT-89 package
Identify transistor marked NM:


Well, it might be an NPN transistor.  There is a picture (https://images.app.goo.gl/6MwJdLNw13JhNEMTA) of something claiming to be a 50V 3A ROHM 2SCR533 NPN transistor with an NM marking.  It would probably make the hunt easier if you could show more of the PCB and explain what the circuit does (even if just "power supply" or "PCB in a coffee machine").

I think @Tony is correct, the photos match lcsc's listing for the 2SCR533P5T100 and 2SCR533PT100. The latter is NRND and the difference between the two appears to be grade related- the electrical and mechanical specs and even the temperature range appear to be identical. One is optionally available in automotive grade HZG (the obsolescent one).
The P5 photo:

